# Associate image file types (UTIs) with iOS App -- Doesn't show 'Open in...' in mail / safari

Tags: ios, ipad, uti

I have an app that opens multiple file types, but image files seem to be a different story.  In Mail and Safari, the options for most file types with associated apps are 'Open In...' or 'Open In [AppName]' (if there is only one), however, since images are embedded as rich-text within emails and web pages, the option only exists to 'Save Image' and 'Copy'

Is it possible to associate an iOS app with image file types, and open images directly in the app, or do they have to all be saved to the photo library, then imported from there (please say no!)

Here are the image file associations from my plist:

```
    <dict>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.tiff</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Same problem here, tried many settings - but can't get it working... Mail.app can't render these images - so only a blue ? is saved to Photos...

Comment: Did you solve this problem?